# API 16.0 Retiring Summer21 - Excel Connector workarounds?

Tags: salesforceexcelconnector

With the [imminent retirement of API versions through 20.0](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000351312&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1), I'm thinking about Excel Connector (Runs for me on API 16.0).

I'm looking for a good way to mimic its features or to get it to work with later API versions. There are some other products (XL-Connector, etc) out there, but I'd prefer to find a way to keep using EC.

I believe Excel Connector uses the Office Toolkit; is there a way to update that toolkit to support a later API version? I know I can update the Excel Connector code, but most API versions don't seem to work with it.

Or should I just bite the bullet and deal with not getting instant gratification on updating specific fields or loading records and getting IDs returned immediately? I'd rather find a product that can replicate what I have right now (that is also free).

Comment: The enabler4excel app is wicked powerful but not free.  I think pricing is fairly reasonable.  Can't speak to the rest but the app is prob worth a trial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the repository for the Excel Connector in the [Google Code Archive](https://code.google.com/archive/p/excel-connector/), although it seems to be short on actual usable source code.

It might be possible to extract the underlying VBA source code from the .xla file. Although the real work sounds like it is done in another COM object that was also created by Salesforce.

Comment: Yes. I have actually created my own customized version by modifying the VBA (shudder) and I like it a lot. It depends on the Office Toolkit, though, so it's limited to API 16.0 and one other, I believe (both below 20.0).

Answer (score 1):

I have found that if you change the API version to 21 in the standard excel connector implementation, although the query wizard no longer works, it still supports querying records as well as updating/creating new ones. You just have to know how to build out the format it expects (SObject name in the upper left column, filters to the right of that, column headers below that).